Google Maps has stopped giving me spoken instructions when I ride public transport, how do I turn it back on?
Google maps always used to speak audible instructions like "stay on the 16 for 4 stops" and "get off at Dam Square".
It's suddenly stopped doing that as of late. The text notifications still appear, but no spoken instructions.
Such instructions are still spoken while driving, walking or cycling, it's just for public transit that they're gone.
How to I get them back?
I use Google Maps 11.140.0104 (#1067638495) on Android 14 (Google Pixel)
